# C# FrameworkCore and MySQL: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

Need some help here... I am copying code directly from one of my school classes, and they show the result in their code, but each time I run it, I get the following exception error:

> Exception has occurred:
>   CLR/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException An unhandled
>   exception of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll: 'An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.' 
>   Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more
>   details.  Innermost exception      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
>   : Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`movies`.`film_actor`, CONSTRAINT `film_actor_actor` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`ActorId`) REFERENCES `actor` (`actorid`))    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.d__1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ResultSet.cs:line
>   44

Here is the method being called:

```
internal static void DeleteItem()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Delete an Actor");

    Console.WriteLine("Enter an Actor ID");
    var actorId = Console.ReadLine().ToInt();

    var actor = MoviesContext.Instance.Actors.SingleOrDefault(a => a.ActorId == actorId);
    if (actor == null) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Actor with id {actorId} not found.");
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Existing Actors");
        WriteActors();

        MoviesContext.Instance.Actors.Remove(actor);

        MoviesContext.Instance.SaveChanges();

        Console.WriteLine("With actor removed.");
        WriteActors();
    }
}
```

I have checked my code over and over again and it matches the instructor's code perfectly. Unfortunately, no one is addressing my question through the college Blackboard, so I brought my question here.

The framework reverse-engineered the database to build all of the scaffolding for the code. The program is throwing this exception when the MySQL statement for `SaveChanges()` is sent.

However, it must be from this table, because `SaveChanges()` is used in an earlier part of the code for something else, and it doesn't throw any errors.

Ideas? This is driving me Looney! Thanks. :)

```
Using:

C# 
ConsoleTables 
EntityFrameworkCore 
 + .Design 
 + .Tools         // Used as a DotNetCliToolReference 
 + .Tools.DotNet  // Used as a DotNetCliToolReference 
 + .MySql 
 + .MySql.Design
```

I don't know anything about constraints, but here is the section of code I found that the framework generated that may be a contributor:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FilmActor>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.FilmId, e.ActorId });

                entity.ToTable("film_actor");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.ActorId)
                    .HasName("film_actor_actor_idx");

                entity.Property(e => e.FilmId).HasColumnType("int(11)");

                entity.Property(e => e.ActorId).HasColumnType("int(11)");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Actor)
                    .WithMany(p => p.FilmActor)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ActorId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("film_actor_actor");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Film)
                    .WithMany(p => p.FilmActor)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.FilmId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("film_actor_film");
            });
```

Perhaps I'm not using this model correctly somewhere?

**RESOLUTION**

After much help below I was able to accomplish the fix by simply creating a loop that went through the associated table **film_actor** and deleted any rows with the **ActorId** that was related to the actor being deleted. Here is the quick loop I put in before the `SaveChanges()` method gets executed:

```
foreach (var tatertot in MoviesContext.Instance.FilmActors) {
     if(tatertot.ActorId == actorId) {
          MoviesContext.Instance.FilmActors.Remove(tatertot);
     }
}
```

I'd like to thank everyone for their help. I'm sure I'll have more as this class goes on! Thank you. :)

Comment: Your movie class has foreignkey ActorId, either you need to set it null or delete the row from movie table as well.

Comment: I appreciate all of the help so far. I feel lost, though. All of the database-handling was created by the Entity Framework and the database was distributed at the beginning of our class. We've had no direct interaction with the database and the framework handles all of the MySQL calls. Not very clear on how I should approach this.

Comment: I found information regarding the 'film_actor_actor" reference in the framework-generated code. Is there something in here I need to focus on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the vital piece of information:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (movies.film_actor, CONSTRAINT film_actor_actor FOREIGN KEY (ActorId) REFERENCES actor (actorid).

If I'm reading the details correctly, what that means is that there is a value in the column `film_actor_actor` in `movies.film_actor` that points to the id (in the column `ActorId`) of the actor you are trying to delete.

The foreign key constraint means you can't delete the actor before removing the `film_actor` pointing to it first, because if you did, the `film_actor` would be **pointing to a non-existing row, which would render your database inconsistent.**

**Solution:** You need to delete any and all references to an actor row before you can delete the actor row itself.

Comment: So, I found film_actor_actor in movies.film_actor as a foreign key constraint. I also see ActorId values in the table linking it to FilmId values. Do I need to loop through and delete these references first before I can delete the actor?

Comment: So, I designed a quick and dirty loop to go through film_actor table and locate any entries with the ActorId and remove them. I also implimented the same idea in methods later detailed by the class that did not work in my code either. Here is what I came up with:

`foreach (var tatertot in MoviesContext.Instance.FilmActors) {
                            if(tatertot.ActorId == actorId) {
                                MoviesContext.Instance.FilmActors.Remove(tatertot);
                            }
                }`

This successfully removed all of the tatertots.

Comment: @4verage Well done, glad to be useful. Good of you too share the final resolution of the problem too! :)

Comment: Entity Framework performs cascade deletion automatically, doesn't it?